# Unable to deserialize an xml node with a url containing a query string - .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to receive xml request, but I am not able to bind to xml element because of "&" in `recording_url` node.

I have the following xml request.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<request> 
<charge>2312</charge>
<reason>RING</reason>
<hangup>none</hangup>
<recording_url>https://abc.testnow.com/call_recordings_wav.php?sid=G112Qt7S&ks=7273996885894aef526d566605aeed67</recording_url>
</request>
```

My web api code :

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("cdr")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public async Task<int> CDACallback([xmlelement]request CDaCallbackModel)
{
}
```

added below line in startup.cs
`services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();`

Getting below error message in postman.

```json
{
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "An error occurred while deserializing input data."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|8f5da348-4786fb0f473302ff."
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably inform the other api that they are not encoding the url content, or consult them about how to handle the response. In the meantime you can define your own formatter to handle the xml the way you'd like

#### Registering a custom formatter in `Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(o => {
        var xmlInputFormatter = new CustomXmlFormatter(o);
        o.InputFormatters.Add(xmlInputFormatter);
        // Optionally add the default xml output formatter if you need to also respond in xml
        var xmlOutputFormatter = new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter();
        o.OutputFormatters.Add(xmlOutputFormatter);
    });
}
```

#### Simple formatter that converts `&` to `&amp;`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;

namespace XML_serialize
{
    public class CustomXmlFormatter : XmlSerializerInputFormatter
    {
        public CustomXmlFormatter(MvcOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override XmlReader CreateXmlReader(Stream readStream, Encoding encoding)
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(readStream, encoding);
            var writer = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
            // This pattern will ignore already encoded charecters
            var re = new Regex("&(?!.{3};)");
            var startPosition = readStream.Position;

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var encoded = re.Replace(line, "&amp;");
                writer.WriteLine(encoded);
            }

            writer.Flush();
            writer.BaseStream.Position = startPosition;
            var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(writer.BaseStream);

            return xmlReader;
        }
    }
}
```

This simple implementation creates a custom **InputFormatter** by extending the existing xml input formatter and overriding the `CreateXmlReader`. It just reads all the text ahead and converts any `&` characters to `&amp;` before passing it to the default xml reader implementation. It uses a regex to skip accidentally replacing `&` characters that are part of already encoded content

#### Controller action that uses xml formatting

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("cdr")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public string CDACallback(CDaCallbackModel request)
{
   _logger.LogInformation(request.recording_url);

    return request.recording_url;
}
```

#### The model

```cs
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XML_serialize
{
    [XmlRootAttribute("request")]
    public class CDaCallbackModel
    {
        public int charge { get; set; } = 0;

        public string reason { get; set; } = "DEFAULT";

        public string hangup { get; set; } = "DEFAULT";

        public string recording_url { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape specific XML characters, replace `&` with `&amp;`

Refer to this [artical](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_xml_escape.html) for more details.

Comment: Xml input is coming from other Api, Its like callback url. So I don't have option to escape xml characters before its my api.  Is there way to overcome this ?